# Javascript image slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an images slideshow on one page of a website i've been developing for someone, yet on another the same code will not run.

Can anybody assist with the issue. The code can be found in the following places:

(working): www.theperfectpic.co.uk/productlist.php

(not working): www.theperfectpic.co.uk

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compared two sources and noticed that you are missing an initial call in the second one:

first one:

```
    ...
    fantasystep=1
    //call function "slideit3()" every 2.5 seconds
    setTimeout("slideit3()",2500)
}
setTimeout("slideit3()",2000)
```

second one:

```
    ...
    homestep=1
    //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
    setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}
// you are missing "setTimeout("slideit()",2500)" here
```

SUggestions:

- Don't miss semicolons in the end of each line.
- using eval() is not a good idea, consider using array instead. [Here is a full article of how to use arrays in JS](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_obj_array.asp)

Comment: thank you, can you possibly give me an example, sorry my javascript knowledge is very limited

Comment: included a link, check that one please. was slide issue fixed?